# UV Unwrap node working with Eevee but not with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, geometry-nodes

I did that simple setup, and something is wrong, but I don't know what it is...

The uv coordinates are correct when I use the material preview / eevee engine, but when I switch to cycles, the coordinates seems to be 0, 0, 0,

It is a pretty strange behaviour...

I know I could go the destructive way, and apply the gn modifier, then convert the attibute to a uv map, but it's not really a valid solution.
Did I missed something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell you for sure if this is a bug or why exactly this doesn't work, but the fact is:
If you name your attribute "uv", then it just doesn't work in *Cycles*.

You can call the attribute whatever you want. "xyz", "kasperl" or "uv_map", all will work, but just not "uv".

[image]

You don't need the node `Split Edges` either, by the way. You can put the selection of the first point directly into the input *Seam* of the node `UV Unwrap` to get the desired result.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.3+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I expected something simple like that, but I wasn't able to find the problem!